# Atualização de dados no SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes campos: `Nome(VARCHAR)`, `Email(VARCHAR)`, `Credito(INT)`

Queria saber como, ou com qual comando, faço para diminuir ou aumentar o campo `Credito`.

Sei que tem que usar o `UPDATE` mas já tentei diversas formas e não consegui.

Comment: Se desejar uma resposta mais focada, coloque qual banco de dados está usando, que tecnologia do PHP está está usando para acessá-lo, e se possível como você está tentando fazer o `update` mesmo que errado. Tente colocar um código do que você tentou. Aí fica mais fácil indicar onde está errando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não deu muitos detalhes do que está utilizando, nem mostrou o que tentou então vou te dar uma resposta genérica para incrementar o valor de um para o campo no MySQL que eu acho que é o DB provável que está usando (eu melhoro se focar mais sua pergunta):

```
$sql = "UPDATE tabela SET Credito = Credito + 1 WHERE Email = '$email'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/SqlIncrement.php).

Estou partindo do princípio que a variável está [devidamente sanitizada](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Ou pode usar uma [forma parametrizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101) para executar mas a *query* SQL será igua a esta acima.