# SQL - Atualizar sem perder os valores

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom pessoal a minha dúvida é o seguinte eu gostaria de atualizar um valor no "Banco de Dados" sem perder o valor lá já alocado, Bom para melhor entendimento da minha dúvida eu irie citar um exemplo:
Tenho uma TABELA CHAMADO: Clientes ; Com colunas: nome,idade,frase.

Tenho os seguintes dados lá > 
nome      idade   frase
lucas     20      bom

Eu gostaria de atualizar a frase sem perder oque já tem nela ou seja:

```
UPDATE Clientes
SET frase='dia'
WHERE nome='lucas';
```

Ou seja gostaria que ele não mudasse a frase para "dia" E sim concatenar, Queria que ficasse> bomdia.
Ele atualiza mantendo o valor que já tem lá.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: `SET frase= frase +'dia'` ?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43907/101

Comment: @rray no caso de inteiros, poderia colocar `SET cont = cont + '1'` que funcionaria como um contador?

Comment: Eu já tentei desta forma porem não funciona, ele atribui 0. Sim Ivcs se for do tipo int você fazendo desta forma ele faz a soma e atribui sem problemas, É uma pena que no tipo varchar ele não concatena :( .

Comment: Tem [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) também.

Comment: @Viniam uma forma mais trivial seria antes do update fazer uma consulta buscando a coluna frase, apos isso concatenar com a linguagem que esteja usando e por último fazer o update normalmente.

Comment: Sim eu já pensei nisso, porem desta forma eu teria que realizar 2 consultas, eu quero fazer algo mais prático apenas uma concatenação de leve, Entendeu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando a função CONCAT você consegue isso.

```
UPDATE Clientes SET frase = CONCAT(frase, 'dia') WHERE nome='lucas';
```

Exemplo funcional [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ec685/1).

Comment: Obrigado querido, Eu havia achado o mesmo exemplo em uma pagina aqui no Overflow, Eu já iria postar aqui para a galera rsrs, mas como você postou primeiro tá ótimo, Obrigado pela ajuda!. FUNCIONANDO PERFEITAMENTE!.

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como válida, assim facilita depois pra quem for pesquisar.